# How can i hide flat rate shipping method when free shipping is available in magento 2.1.5?

Tags: cart, shipping, shipping-methods, magento2.1.5, free-shipping

I have set free shipping when amount is greater than 300rs, but when amount is greater than rs 300 two methods are still showing.

How can I hide the Flat rate when cart amount is greater than Rs 300.?

Comment: Please specify magento version

Comment: Version is 2.1.5